# Splitting digits only from list prints in python and save into CSV

Tags: html, python-3.x, list, split, export-to-csv

how to split the numbers in the output (the list) its large though and then **export into CSV**

`print(list)`
output

```
['id=31535&requestId=16152331&ln=143833']
['id=31539&requestId=16152331&ln=143833']
['id=31540&requestId=16152331&ln=143832']
['id=31541&requestId=16152331&ln=143831']
['id=31542&requestId=16152331&ln=143845']
```

Comment: Is this a list of list? What does the expected output look like? Also, what have you done so far to address this?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi [at]JoeFerndz Sorry its not clear to you, will improve it thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you could do this:

```
import re
import csv
fn = 'csvtest1.csv'
din = [['id=31535&requestId=16152331&ln=143833'],
['id=31539&requestId=16152331&ln=143833'],
['id=31540&requestId=16152331&ln=143832'],
['id=31541&requestId=16152331&ln=143831'],
['id=31542&requestId=16152331&ln=143845']]
with open(fn, 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
    for itm in din:
        writer.writerow(re.findall(r'\d+', str(itm)))
```

This would yield csv formatted file named csvtest1.csv which contains the following:

```
'Col1',    'Col2',      'Col3'
 31535,    16152331,   143833
 31539,    16152331,   143833
 31540,    16152331,   143832
 31541,    16152331,   143831
 31542,    16152331,   143845
​
```

Comment: `pathlist = path.split("/")`
`    # print(pathlist)` with this we i'm only printing one line only when there is all the list May be loop ? `['31535', '16152331', '143833']` 
```for itm in pathlist:
    print(re.findall(r'\d+', str(itm))) ```

Comment: I am not sure I follow?  If you would share the code used to acquire the files and output to csv, I maybe able to add further help

Comment: Its fine the for loop was misplaced. 
`
    ['31535', '16152331', '143833']
    ['31539', '16152331', '143833']
    ['31540', '16152331', '143832']
    ['31541', '16152331', '143831']
    ['31542', '16152331', '143845']
`
> Second part now how to save the the `printed output list into csv`?  that would be great

Comment: thanks @itprorh66... that actually already declaring the list `din`. what i need is to print all the list from console, let me tweek it if i may