# csv writing last row only in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, export-to-csv, import-csv

below is console output parsed from url saving only last row into csv

```
['id=35942&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043845']
['id=35943&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043833']
['id=35944&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043832']
['id=35945&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043831']
['id=35946&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043845']
```

[image: pythonprints]
import re
import csv

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Submit') // link attributes
len(links)
for link in links:
    a = link.get_attribute('href')  //getting all the links 
    # print(a)
    parsed = urlparse(a)  //parsing the urls
    path = parsed[-2]  
    pathlist = path.split("/")
   # itm = len(pathlist)
    print(pathlist)
    with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for itm in pathlist:
            writer.writerow(re.findall(r'\d+', str(itm)))
```

and csv file is writing only last row
`35946,1615320149894,1000043845`

Answer (score 0):

Each time your loop starts, you rewrite the document erasing all the old output. Just move the open outside the loop as shown:

```py
import re
import csv

links = [
    ['id=35942&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043845'],
    ['id=35943&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043833'],
    ['id=35944&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043832'],
    ['id=35945&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043831'],
    ['id=35946&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043845']
]
with open('myfile2.csv', 'w') as f:
    for link in links:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for itm in link:
            writer.writerow(re.findall(r'\d+', str(itm)))
```

Comment: not reading from `with open ('myfile.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')` its all writing into csv file

Comment: That's just what I used in the example since you didn't provide any sample data so I just wrote a csv to hold multiple URLs. I was asking for clarification for the top half of your code.

Comment: Sorry just saw your edit. This problem was a lot simpler than I thought.

Comment: yeah thanks, b'cally getting all the links and splitng it up. then only numbers printing into console which needed into csv.

Comment: `links = [
    ['id=35942&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043845'],
    ['id=35943&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043833'],
    ['id=35944&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043832'],
    ['id=35945&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043831'],
    ['id=35946&requestId=1615320149894&ln=1000043845']
]`dont want to copy from console how can it worked out without pasting all the output into `links = []`   already have this solution [itworkshere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537167/splitting-digits-only-from-list-prints-in-python-and-save-into-csv/66539264)

Comment: @Blodvault this i already tried and works well before i put this question. Do not want listing to be copied before. What i printed on console should be in to csv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229708/discussion-between-bloodvault-and-gps).

Comment: Sorry that too printing the last list value into CSV, will wait for the answer